# Make react-day-picker show OverlayWrapper upwards

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

Can `react-day-picker` show the OverlayWrapper upwards when needed?
I've tried to place it to the bottom of the page of my app. Also I've tested on your site, looks the same. See screenshots.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[overlayComponent]`[1](http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPickerInput#overlayComponent) prop to put the day picker in your own component with custom alignment behavior.

Comment: @Sandhu not personally. But we are planning to adopt popper.js for fixing this kind of issues!